# Remove Specific Pattern at the end of the string awk

Tags: regex, awk, gsub

I have String like below,

```
Abc \ \          <--- This is With space at the end
Abc \ \          <--- This is Without space at the end
Abc\ \
Abc \\
Abc\\
Abc\ 
Abc \
```

Expected result for all the above strings,

```
Abc
```

In short if in the end of the string there is any combination pattern of space & \ then i want to remove it.
I want to do this using awk..

Please help with this...

Comment: So, did you try anything?

Answer (score 3):

To apply a single substitution to each line, use sed:

```
sed 's/[ \]*$//g' file
```

Match all combinations of spaces and backslashes at the end of each line and replace with nothing.

Answer (score 1):

With awk you could do something like `awk '{gsub(/[ \\]+$/,"")}1' file`

Test:

```
$ cat -A file
Abc \ \ $
Abc \ \$
Abc\ \$
Abc \\$
Abc\\$
Abc\ $
Abc \ $

$ awk '{gsub(/[ \\]+$/,"")}1' file
Abc
Abc
Abc
Abc
Abc
Abc
Abc
```

The regex matches sequences of consecutive spaces and backslashes in the end of the line.